# Creating effective query with multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, union

I am trying to make a query for site searching. What I need to do with this query is I want to select four main columns according to search keyword (tutors, institutes, subjects, cities). when typing keyword the query must check this four tables and need to display search result under this four categories. when displaying search result I need to add some values to make meaningful search result. Eg: Think displaying tutors under tutors category as a search result I need to display his/her name, city, profile image etc.

Its something like this.

```
**Tutors** 
  tutor's name
  city
  profile image
**institutes** 
  institute's name
  city
  profile image 
**subjects**
  subject name
  category name which belong this subject
**cities** 
  city name
  district name which city belong etc...
```

I tried it something like this

```
$q = "SELECT keyword, col, city_name, image_name, tutor_code 
        FROM (
            SELECT tutor_name AS keyword, 'Tutors' AS col, IFNULL(c1.city_name, '') city_name, IFNULL(ti.image_name, '') image_name, tutor_code FROM tutors AS t
            LEFT JOIN address a ON t.address_id = a.address_id
            LEFT JOIN city c1 ON a.city_id = c1.city_id 
            LEFT JOIN tutor_images ti ON t.tutor_id = ti.tutor_id AND ti.image_type = 'profile'
            UNION
            SELECT subject_name AS keyword, 'Subject' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM subjects 
            UNION
            SELECT city_name AS keyword, 'City' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM city
            UNION
            SELECT institute_name AS keyword, 'Institute' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code FROM institutes AS i
            LEFT JOIN address a ON i.address_id = a.address_id
            LEFT JOIN city c2 ON a.city_id = c2.city_id 
            LEFT JOIN institute_images ii ON i.institute_id = ii.institute_id AND ii.image_type = 'profile'             
        ) s
      WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
      LIMIT 10";
```

this query work about 50% but cant get to work in 100%. Problem is it is not display city name and profile image under institutes category, cant display district name and category names under cities and subjects fields. And also I would like to this kind of query is ineffective and does it waste time and resources?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) this with sample data?

Comment: can I get a solution without sqlfiddle? Its a hard working I have to work with more tables.

Answer (score 0):

`UNION` tries to put the results of all of your `SELECT` queries into one big table with one set of column names / data types.  The number of columns and the data types of each column for all of your `SELECT` statements must therefore match.  You're already using the keyword which is a useful tactic to separate your types.  I think you can select extra data in the right columns to make this work.

I think what you should do is try that and measure the performance.  Then make separate database calls in parallel and get the results and measure that performance.  I think that they will be comparable with the second being much easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: thanks for response. But your answer is not clear for me. so can you please elaborate it with an example. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT keyword, col, city_name, image_name, tutor_code, district_name, category_name 
FROM (
    SELECT tutor_name AS keyword, 'Tutors' AS col, IFNULL(c1.city_name, '') city_name,  
             IFNULL(ti.image_name, '') image_name, tutor_code, '' district_name, '' category_name 
    FROM tutors AS t 
    LEFT JOIN address a ON t.address_id = a.address_id 
    LEFT JOIN city c1 ON a.city_id = c1.city_id 
    LEFT JOIN tutor_images ti ON t.tutor_id = ti.tutor_id AND ti.image_type = 'profile' 
    UNION
    SELECT subject_name AS keyword, 'Subject' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code, 
             '' district_name, c.category_name 
    FROM subjects s 
    LEFT JOIN category_subjects cs ON s.subject_id = cs.subject_id 
    LEFT JOIN category c ON cs.category_id = c.category_id 
    UNION
    SELECT city_name AS keyword, 'City' AS col, '' city_name, '' image_name, '' tutor_code, 
             district_name, '' category_name 
    FROM city 
    UNION
    SELECT institute_name AS keyword, 'Institute' AS col, IFNULL(c2.city_name, '') city_name, 
             IFNULL(ii.image_name, '')  image_name, institute_code tutor_code, '' district_name, '' category_name
    FROM institutes AS i 
    LEFT JOIN address a ON i.address_id = a.address_id  
    LEFT JOIN city c2 ON a.city_id = c2.city_id  
    LEFT JOIN institute_images ii ON i.institute_id = ii.institute_id AND ii.image_type = 'profile'             
) s
WHERE keyword LIKE '%$queryString%' 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Hello @Saharsh Shah Its nice to see you again. Wait I will check this

Comment: my category_name comes from category table and category_subjects table have which subject belong to which category..

Comment: again city name is not selected to institutes.

Comment: not sure. I use same address and city table for institutes too. but not selecting city for institutes but working with tutors.

Comment: Now Its ok. and another case can I change 'tutor_code' in first line of the query to member_code

Comment: I tried it something like this - SELECT keyword, col, city_name, image_name, IF(tutor_code || institute_code) AS member_code, district_name, category_name

Comment: why I need to change it, I select institute_code then its display under tutor_code column.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24259/discussion-between-tharanga-nuwan-and-saharsh-shah)